# Error in the blog using django, Jade with HTML5 NOT DISPLAY THE POST.

Tags: python, django, html, pug, stylus

I have a simple blog using django, Jade and Stylus. The blog I created have been tested  and no error.

When I run the server the code execute and in the admin site have added 3 posts as an example to see what will be look like. I used if statement for the to show whether empty or display the post, unfortunately display no post, the issue is the all front end are written by jade and stylus and I have not much knowledge to write the blog in Jade just to test have used HTML5. The base.jade and the home.html. I just wonder why not display the post here is the code.

**model.py**

```
from django.db import models from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, RequestContext from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger

class Post(models.Model):
    title     = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    content   = models.TextField()
    created   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated   = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    published = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s" % self.title


def index(request):
    """ Home page """
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published=True).order_by('-created')[:2]

    paginator = Paginator(posts, 2)

    page_num = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    page = paginator.page(page_num)

    try:
        page = paginator.page(page_num)
    except EmptyPage:
        page = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        page = paginator.page(1)

    return render_to_response('home.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**view.py**

```
from vanilla import TemplateView


class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "pages/home.html"

class PostPageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "pages/post.html"

class PrivacyPageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "careers/job_list.jade"

class AboutPageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "pages/about.jade"
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from .views import AboutPageView, HomePageView, PostPageView


urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(regex=r'^$', view=HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),
                       url(regex=r'^post/(?P<id>\d+)/$', view=PostPageView.as_view(), name='post'),
                       url(regex=r'^about/$', view=AboutPageView.as_view(), name='about'),
```

**home.html**

```
{% extends "base.jade"  %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Welcome to JobPlus </h1><hr/>
{% if posts %}
        {% for post in page.objects_list %}
            <h3><a href="/templates/{{ post.id }}">{{ post.title }}</a></h3>
            <i>{{ post.created }}</i>
            <p>{{ post.content|safe|truncatewords:'100' }}</p>
            <hr/>
        {% endfor %}

        <ul class="pagination">

            {% if page.has_previous %}
                <li class="disabled"><a  href="?page={{ page.previous_page_number }}">&laquo;</a></li>
            {% endif %}

                <li><span>{{ page.number }}<span class="sr-only"></span></span></li>

            {% if page.has_next %}
                <li><a href="?page={{ page.next_page_number }}">&raquo;</a></li>
            {% endif %}

        </ul>
    {% else %}
         <p>There are no post! :(</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

**config/urls.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'', include('apps.pages.urls')),
                       url(r'', include('apps.careers.urls')),
                       url(r'', include('apps.contact.urls')),
                       url(r'', include('apps.faq.urls')),
                       url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**base.jade**

```
- load compressed i18n staticfiles
!!! 5
html(lang="en", data-ng-app)
    head
        meta(charset="utf-8")
        meta(http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge")
        title{% block title %}{% endblock %} | {{ site.name }}
        meta(name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0")
        meta(name="description", content="{% block description %}{% endblock %}")
        meta(name="robots", content="{% block robots %}{% endblock %}")
        meta(name="author", content="{% block author %}{% endblock %}")
        link(rel="stylesheet", href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css")
        link(rel="stylesheet", href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css")
        link(rel="shortcut icon", href="{% static 'images/favicon.ico' %}")
        - compressed_css 'style'
        block css
        body
            .navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-static-top(role="navigation")
                .container-fluid
                    .navbar-header
                        button.navbar-toggle(type="button", data-toggle="collapse", data-target=".navbar-collapse")
                            span.sr-only Toggle Navigation
                            span.icon-bar
                            span.icon-bar
                            span.icon-bar
                        a.navbar-brand(href="#") JobPlus

                    .collapse.navbar-collapse
                        ul.nav.navbar-nav.pull-left
                            {% url 'home' as home %}
                            {% if request.path == home %}
                            li.active
                                a(href="{% url 'home' %}") {% blocktrans %}Home{% endblocktrans %}
                            {% else %}
                            li
                                a(href="{% url 'home' %}") {% blocktrans %}Home{% endblocktrans %}
                            {% endif %}
                            {% url 'about' as about %}
                            {% if request.path == about %}
                            li.active
                                a(href="{% url 'about' %}") {% blocktrans %}About us{% endblocktrans %}
                            {% else %}
                            li
                                a(href="{% url 'about' %}") {% blocktrans %}About us{% endblocktrans %}
                            {% endif %}
            .container
                block content
            hr
            .container
                .row-fluid
                    p &copy; &nbsp;
                        a(href="http://{{ site.domain }}") {{ site.name }}
                        &nbsp; {% now "Y" %}
```

Any idea, what I missed or what is maybe wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure your `models.py` is correct? Do you really have a view method in there?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid thanks for your message, my problem is using django-vanilla-views and not sure how to rewrite the view method for this blog. When I run the server there is no any error and I can put the layout of the home page. The same model have tested in other project work very well the different here is I declared the view methods under the class.

Comment: what version of django are you using?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I am using Django= 1.6.2 I saw your blog on Friday try to email you after changed my mind. I thought will wait how will going here first.